# Button hover animation background color not filled fully

Tags: html, css

When you hover over the button on left & right side same space is visible. How can we fix that?
Here is image when you hover on button this is how it looks.

[image]

Here is jsfiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/vct5acc0/1/

Css code is here :-

```
body {
   background-color: #4F4BFA;
  }
.btn1 {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.btn-cmn {
    width: 175px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution, inspired by Kuba's first proposition:
(the one which added an inset shadow on the hover, not the updated one!)
See my comments in the CSS code, only 2 modifications.

```css
body {
  background-color: #4F4BFA;
}

.btn1 {
  border: none; /* Modified */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; /* Added */
}

.btn-cmn {
  width: 175px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 26px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-hover-effect {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -moz-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -ms-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.btn-hfix1 {
  height: 53px;
}

.button-hover-effect.white {
  border-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.button-hover-effect.white:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.button-hover-effect::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 26px;
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: -o-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform-origin: right center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  -ms-transform-origin: right center;
}

.button-hover-effect:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform-origin: left center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;
}

.button-hover-effect.white::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.button-hover-effect .str {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-cmn btn1 button-hover-effect white btn-hfix1">
  <span class="str">Know more</span>
</button>
```

I've only set the `border` to `none`, and then added an `inset` `box-shadow`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: To get it a bit cleaner u can do `.btn1 {  border:none; /*changed*/
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; /*added*/
}` But good job anyway

Answer (score 1):

Quick and "dirty". Remove the original border on hover and add an inset shadow (as a border) to see still a border while the transformation.

Updated:

```
.btn1 {
  border:none; /*changed*/
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; /*added*/
}
```

```css
body {
   background-color: #4F4BFA;
  }
.btn1 {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff;
}
.btn-cmn {
    width: 175px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button-hover-effect {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
    transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -webkit-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -moz-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -o-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -ms-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.btn-hfix1 {
    height: 53px;
}
.button-hover-effect.white {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
}


.button-hover-effect.white:hover {
    color: #000;
    border:0px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff;
}
.button-hover-effect::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 26px;
    transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -o-transition: -o-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0,1);
    -o-transform: scale(0,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform-origin: right center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    -moz-transform-origin: right center;
    -o-transform-origin: right center;
    -ms-transform-origin: right center;
    
}
.button-hover-effect:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -o-transform: scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    -ms-transform-origin: left center;
    border:5px solid #fff;
}
.button-hover-effect.white::before {
    background-color: #fff;
    
}
.button-hover-effect .str {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-cmn btn1 button-hover-effect white btn-hfix1">
             <span class="str">Know more</span>
            </button>
```

Comment: When we un-hover, we can see the problem reappearing on the right of the button.

Comment: I know, thats why i said "dirty" and its minimal.

Comment: I did something inspired by your dirty solution. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Have updated the fiddle. Please check

```
.button-hover-effect.white:hover {
  color: #000;
  border: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vct5acc0/8/

Comment: there is no difference between your fiddle and question

Comment: Check again, i have made the changes in css.

Comment: where is the border when we hover the button?

Comment: We don't need that, there's no change in size of button before and after hover.

Comment: what if the questioner need that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169737/discussion-between-abhay-srivastav-and-zuber).

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
   background-color: #4F4BFA;
  }
.btn1 {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.button-hover-effect.white:hover {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-cmn {
    width: 175px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-cmn:hover {
    width: 175px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button-hover-effect {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
    transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -webkit-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -moz-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -o-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -ms-transition: color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.btn-hfix1 {
    height: 53px;
}
.button-hover-effect.white {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
.button-hover-effect.white:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.button-hover-effect::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 26px;
    transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -o-transition: -o-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0,1);
    -o-transform: scale(0,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform-origin: right center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    -moz-transform-origin: right center;
    -o-transform-origin: right center;
    -ms-transform-origin: right center;
}
.button-hover-effect:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -o-transform: scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    -ms-transform-origin: left center;
}
.button-hover-effect.white::before {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.button-hover-effect .str {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-cmn btn1 button-hover-effect white btn-hfix1">
             <span class="str">Know more</span>
            </button>
```

Comment: Where is the effect when we hover the button?

Comment: When you hover you can see the effect of the change from blue to white

Comment: you have changed initial hover effect, what if the questioner wants the same effect?

Comment: When we un-hover, we can see the problem reappearing on the right of the button. And it moves vertically.